# Mapbox GL Create Button for Each Feature

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm completely stumped on this one, thanks in advance for any advice!

[Here's a link to the map I'm working on](http://hthompson.me/sf_macgregor.html). All the functionality is working correctly, but I'd like add two things:

1. Create a list of buttons for each feature
2. Have each button trigger the following click function to it's corresponding feature:

   ```
               map.on('click', function(e) {


               var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['macgregor'] });

               map.flyTo({center: [0, 0], zoom: 2});
               map.setLayoutProperty('selectedarea', 'visibility', 'none');
               // map.setLayoutProperty('selectedRoad2', 'visibility', 'none');

               if (!features.length) {
                   return;     
               }
               if (typeof map.getLayer('selectedarea') !== "undefined" ){         
                   map.removeLayer('selectedarea');
                   map.removeSource('selectedarea');
                   // map.setFilter('MacGregor65_Data_Fills')  ; 
               }
               if (features.length) {
               var clickedFeature = features[0].geometry;
               var lonLatArr = splitLatLon(clickedFeature);
               var featureBounds = featureBoundaries(lonLatArr[0], lonLatArr[1]);

               map.fitBounds(featureBounds, {padding: 200});

               }

               var feature = features[0];
               // alert(features.length);
               //I think you could add the vector tile feature to the map, but I'm more familiar with JSON
               console.log(feature.toJSON());


               map.addSource('selectedarea', {
                   "type":"geojson",
                   "data": feature.toJSON()
               });

               map.addLayer({
                   "id": "selectedarea",
                   "type": "fill",
                   "source": "selectedarea",
                   "layout": {
                       },
                   "paint": {
                       "fill-color": "yellow",
                       "fill-opacity": .2
                       // "fill-width": 8
                   }
               });
           });
   ```